# Is there any way to apply FLIRT signatures through a script like idapython?

Tags: ida, idapython, ida-plugin, flirt-signatures

I'm writing a script to find out how many functions were recognized after applying a **FLIRT** signature library, I'm using idapython I would like to know if I can apply the signatures by the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply FLIRT signatures using `plan_to_apply_idasgn` function from `ida_funcs` module.

From the [official API documentation](https://hex-rays.com/wp-content/static/products/ida/support/idapython_docs/ida_funcs.html):

> `def plan_to_apply_idasgn(*args) ‑> int`
>
> Add a signature file to the list of planned signature files.
> **plan_to_apply_idasgn(fname) -> int**
> **fname**: file name. should not contain directory part. (C++:
> const char *)
> **return**: 0 if failed, otherwise number of planned (and applied)
> signatures

If you have an older version of IDA (before `7.4`), you can use `idc.ApplySig` function (see [link](https://hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/ida74_idapython_no_bc695/) and [link](https://hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/ida74_idapython_no_bc695_porting_guide/)).